# rvm and different versions of a system library

Tags: ruby, libraries, rvm, shared-libraries

I need to run a set of tests against the *same ruby version* and *same gemset* but with different versions of a .so library.

Therefor I need to have two ruby installations (for the same version 1.8.7), each one pointing to a different set of .so files. How can I do that?

Gemset usage is already too late because library binding is done when rvm install installs a ruby version.

Comment: its best if you hit #rvm irc channel, its an advanced query and people are usually available for help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rishav, I got the answer through twitter from god himself (aka rvm creator), I can download the real version and the version tagged 1_8_7 on the repository.

Its a hack and will work fine with up to 4~5 different configurations (using tag, revision number, revision date and so on)

Problema solved